# What are the prerequisties of Riemannian geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I have graduated with a degree in mathematics. I have covered multivariable calculus, linear algebra and basic topology during my degree. Also I have studied differential geometry of curves and surfaces (do Carmo's book) on my own, and currently I am studying differential geometry from Tu's book, introduction to manifolds. Do I need to cover the whole book to be prepared for Riemannian geometry? Do I need material such as differential forms, integration on manifolds, Lie algebras, De Rham cohomology?
I am willing to study either from Do Carmo's book Riemannian geometry or Lee's book. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to be prepared for Riemannian geometry? Which book you choose depends a lot on what your ultimate goal is. It also depends if you like the author's style.

Comment: For either book one will also need basic understanding of covering theory (do Carmo's "Curves and surfaces" contains enough material on this, if I remember correctly). Thus, you are good to go. Start reading.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/19505/90655